# Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined in multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mustache

I am uploading a text file using multer. I need to get the content of the text file. So, I am using buffer.toString('utf8'). But, it is giving me an error message which is as follows:  `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`.Does anyone have any idea that why is it happening? Also, I have checked that `req.file is not undefined`

My code is as follows:

```
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
function setupRoutes(app) {
  //@TODO add appropriate routes

  const base = app.locals.base;
    // app.get(`${base}/search.html`, doSearch(app));
    app.get(`${base}/add.html`, createDocsForm(app));
    app.post(`${base}/add.html`, upload.single('file'), doAdd(app));
    app.get(`${base}/:id`, showContent(app));// must be last
  }

function doAdd(app){
  return async function(req, res) {
    try{
       //console.log(req.file.buffer.toString(`utf8`));
      // if(req.file === undefined) console.log("req is undefined");
      const fileContent = req.file.buffer.toString('utf8');
      // const fileContent = req.file;
      let fileName = req.file.originalname;
      fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
      const obj = {
        name: fileName,
        content: fileContent
      }
      const a = await app.locals.model.uploadDoc(obj);
      res.redirect(`${app.locals.base}/${fileName}`);
    }catch(err){
        if(req.file == undefined){
          const err = "Select file to upload";
          const model = {base:app.locals.base, err:err};
          const html = doMustache(app,'add',model);
          res.send(html);
        }
        else{
          const errors= wsErrors(err);
          const model = {base:app.locals.base, errors:errors};
          const html = doMustache(app,'add',model);
          res.send(html);
        }
   } }
}
```

Comment: Apparently `buffer` is not in the request. Did you mean `req.file.buffer` as in the commented code?

Comment: Yeah. I have done the correction. But it is still giving me the same error message. Although, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The error points that `req.file.buffer` is undefined.

Comment: Why do you think that req.file.buffer is undefined?

Comment: You said that `req.file` is not `undefined` (which appears correct else you would've gotten 'cannot read property `buffer` of undefined'). The error is that there is no `toString` property on `undefined` and the only object you are attempting this is on `req.file.buffer` so it's `undefined`. Looking at the master API docs, it should be there, but you'll have to provide version info and any pertinent express configurations or middleware that modifies the request.

Comment: req.file.buffer should not be undefined as req.file is not equal to undefined. I have checked this condition

Comment: I'm not sure what your storage configurations are, but `buffer` seems to be closely linked with `MemoryStorage`.

Comment: I have done some edits in order to let you know about configuration. Please see that.

Comment: The version of multer is 1.4.1

Answer (score 2):

You have conflicting code:

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
```

If you want `file.buffer`, you'll need to import without `dest` like:

```
const upload = multer({});
```

Your import implies `DiskStorage`, but multer only defines `buffer` on files using `MemoryStorage`:

```
function Multer (options) {
  if (options.storage) {
    this.storage = options.storage
  } else if (options.dest) {
    this.storage = diskStorage({ destination: options.dest })
  } else {
    this.storage = memoryStorage()
  }

  this.limits = options.limits
  this.preservePath = options.preservePath
  this.fileFilter = options.fileFilter || allowAll
}
```

See [multer's storage selection code](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/index.js#L14) and [MemoryStorage](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/storage/memory.js#L8).

---

With enough finagling you could multiplex storages, perhaps by writing your own storage multiplexer composite:

```
class StorageMultiplexer {
    constructor(...storageBackends) {
        this._storages = storageBackends;
    }

    _handleFile(req, file, cb) {
        this._storages.forEach(s => s._handleFile(req, file, cb));
    }

    _removeFile(req, file, cb) {
        this._storages.forEach(s => s._removeFile(req, file, cb));
    }
}

var diskStorage = require('./storage/disk')
var memoryStorage = require('./storage/memory')

const upload = multer({
    dest: 'uploads/',
    storage: new StorageMultiplexer(diskStorage, memoryStorage)
});
```

**This code is not tested and is merely a demonstration**

Please read [StorageEngine.md](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/816d984891050e1a53b89f5ff3d7fee33aa5f37b/StorageEngine.md) for more direction.

Comment: It seems that you are right. Thank you for your help